# Change text selection to rtl instead of default ltr

Tags: android, webview

I am working on `WebView` in Android. As you know, when we want to select text in `WebView` which has two or more lines, It selects text from **`left to right`** How can I force `WebView` to select text from **`right to left`** ?

Example (Bold double quotation is selection start and next one is end of selection )

Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A **`"`** site that’s free. Free to ask questions, free to answer questions, free to read, free to index **`"`** , built with plain old HTML, no fake rot13 text on the home page, no scammy google-cloaking tactics, no salespeople, no JavaScript windows dropping down in front of the answer asking for $12.95 to go away. You can register if you want to collect karma and win valuable flair that will appear next to your name, but otherwise, it’s just free. And fast. Very, very fast.

I want to select the text as :

`Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A, built with plain old HTML, no`

But default selection text is as below :

`site that's free. Free to ask questions, free to answer questions, free to read, free to index`

Could any one please help me to do like this ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you show me the code of selection?

Comment: Explain better,You desired selection has omitted the text inside "", can you explain the relation with "" symbols?

Comment: @MoshErsan: Just Android WebView select. I 'm not using other external codes.

Comment: @Mohsen Afshin: Tell me what is wrong? Double Quatatitions tell us selected Texts.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the selection direction ought to be encapsulated within the webview (not accessible to developers) and dictated instead by the content of the HTML being viewed. Using the `<bdo dir="rtl">` tag, I can get the JellyBean browser to select as desired, but Ice Cream Sandwich still selects left-to-right. It's possible that support for selection direction may be a recent addition.

Comment: It still selects text in ltr mode!